# Restrict bounds in use-places-autocomplete

Tags: google-places-api, react-google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to restrict the bounds in `use-places-autocomplete` as below

```
  requestOptions: {
      types: ["geocode"],
      fields: [
        "name",
        "address_components",
        "geometry.location",
        "place_id",
        "formatted_address",
      ],
      
      bounds: window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(bounds?.n, bounds?.w),
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: "ke",
      },

      initOnMount: true,
      cache: false,
    },
```

only this does not work. The bounds are gotten from geocode api and set as below

```
setBounds({
      n: results[0].geometry.bounds.getNorthEast(), 
      w: results[0].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest()
    })
```

is there something I am doing wrong

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a working codesandbox that demonstrates the issue so that the community could take a look at it and troubleshoot it better.

Answer (score 1):

*The [request options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest) of Google Maps Places API **except for `input` (e.g. bounds, radius, etc.).|***

This is from use-places-autocomplete **readme** file. It says 'input' (e.g. bounds, radius, etc.) is not supported which means you cannot use 'bounds' with use-places-autocomplete

Answer (score -1):

To **restrict** Place Autocomplete results to the given bounds, try using [`strictBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#restrict-the-search-to-the-current-bounds) to the `requestOptions`. At least that's how it works in the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Comment: There is no "strictBounds" in use-places-autocomplete package

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize this was about react. I'd suggest filing a bug or feature request for the use-places-autocomplete package then; `strictBounds` is available in the JavaScript Places library already.

Comment: I took a look at the [library's repo](https://github.com/wellyshen/use-places-autocomplete), and it looks like the library is using the [Places Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) instead of the [Places Widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget) which uses the `strictBounds`. Is it similar to [locationRestriction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest.locationRestriction)? @miguev